# Jquery or javascript for search

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I have been looking for a script or API that i could use. To be able to search through data from mysql.. 
I have managed to create a dialog box and load all the data from mysql into it..

what i wont to be able to do have a text  box that when u type in there username it searches the data straight away for them and being able to do this without refreshing or close the dialog box...

Anyone who has any idea on how to do this or ahs done it and has code or anything the help is greatly apprenticed and sosry for the lack in knowledge about this kinda stuff i only know the very basic

Answer (score 1):

[AutoComplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin is your choice